# jQuery select value inside neighbourhood TD

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get value inside span with id 'TargetSpan' when user clicks on Input with ID of 'test'
I tried this code but it returns null.

```
$('.PrintReport').click(function (e) {
            alert($(this).parent().find('td:eq(2)').html());

        });
```

---

```
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<span id="TargetSpan" class="Price">0</span>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input id=test type="image"  class="PrintReport" >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<span id="TargetSpan2" class="Price">0</span>
</td>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input id=test2 type="image"  class="PrintReport" >
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for and of course this solution relative to your HTML mark-up and might not work if you change your mark-up.

```
$('.PrintReport').click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().prev().prev().find('.Price').html());
});
```

this is another solution but you have to give every `TargetSpan` and `Test` id's with a number suffix like `TargetSpan1`, `TargetSpan2`, `test1`, `test2`

```
$('.PrintReport').click(function() {
  var id = this.id.replace('test', '');
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('TargetSpan' + id).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.parent()` will return the parent td; try `parent().parent()` or `.closest("tr")`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just select it by the id?

```
$('#TargetSpan').html()
```

Comment: I think I didn't explain the question well please review my question again because I have for example 10 TR s.

Comment: Ok, try something like this:
$(this).parent().prev().prev().find("span").html()

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to use the `id` conventions in your example, this will ALWAYS work, regardless of `td` order.

```
$('.PrintReport').click(function (e) {
    alert($('#TargetSpan' + $(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g,'')).html());
});
```